# Parameterized Remote Trigger is not triggering the remote jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception, jenkins-plugins, version

There are 2 Jenkins A and B. I am triggering Job in A Jenkins and after the build is succeeded, it should trigger a Job in B Jenkins using **Remote Parameterized Job** (Parameterized Remote Trigger) plugin.

I am using the Jenkins and plugin version as follows:
Jenkins A version            - 2.107.2
Jenkins B version            - 2.73.3
Parameterized Remote Trigger version - 2.2.2

When i triggered build job in A Jenkins, it is triggering only 1 build job in B Jenkins (In that particular folder there will be 6 build jobs and all of them has to get triggered) and then it is failing with the below mentioned issue.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.sendHTTPCall(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:980)
10:33:04    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.sendHTTPCall(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:799)
10:33:04    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ParameterizedRemoteTrigger.RemoteBuildConfiguration.perform(RemoteBuildConfiguration.java:556)
10:33:04    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
10:33:04    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
10:33:04 Build step 'Trigger a remote parameterized job' marked build as failure
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The above issue got resolved once we have updated the plugin "Parameterized Remote Trigger" to 3.0.3 and provide the root URL of Jenkins B in Jenkins A configuration and provide the rest of the path till the Job is present in the **Remote Job Name or URL** parameter and hence the above issue got resolved.

Comment: Can you please show screen shoot of your configurations, especially Jenkins server which will get triggered from remote Jenkins job